# Global error handling using axios in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am using axios in vuejs and have a trouble with global error handling while axios call. I'm trying as follow and it not only takes user logout but also executes the code block after the axios call.
  How can I prevent the execution of the axios call promise code section if error occurs.

```
export default {
    created() {
    var self = this;
      if (self.$route.meta.requiresAuth) {
        axios.interceptors.response.use(
          function(response) {
            return response;
          },
          function(error) {
            if (error.response.status == 401) {
              self.$toaster.error("ERROR: Invalid token detected");
                self.logout();
              }
            }
          );
        }
      },
      methods: {
        logout() {
          this.$router.push({ name: "login" });
        }
      }
    }

someFunction() {
  var self = this;
  axios
    .post(
      "url/to/api",
      {},
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "authtoken here"
        }
      }
    )
    .then(response => {
      alert("success");
        otherFunction();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent the execution of the axios call promise code section"? Which lines in your code are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to raise a new error from the error interceptor.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  function(response) {
    return response;
  },
  function(error) {
    if (error.response.status == 401) {
      self.$toaster.error("ERROR: Invalid token detected");
        self.logout();
      }
      throw new Error('Invalid token detected')
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I have added the last line of code, but it doesn't help me with prevent the execution of the promise code. How can I prevent the execution of promise?